# Add a CSS class to an HTML tag with PHP regex

Tags: php, html, regex, wordpress

Can anyone suggest the best way to add a CSS class to an HTML element using PHP?

I need to modify a string which is the content of a WordPress post. If the post has a figure element at the start, I want to extract the element's opening `<figure>` tag and add the CSS class "big-image" to it before putting it back in place. The tag may or may not have a class attribute (with a value in single or double quotes), and it may have other attributes in various orders, so I can't just use preg_replace: I'll need to pull the tag out and run it through some logic with conditions to allow for these possibilities.

For example, I could have:

`<figure id="foo" data-track="bar" class="fig">`

or

`<figure class='fig bah' id='foo' data-track='bar'>`

or

`<figure data-track="bar">`

or just

`<figure>`

I only need to do this if the figure is the first thing in the content - if there's a figure anywhere else I'll ignore it. I've got as far as this first condition

```
if ( strpos( trim( $content ), '<figure' ) == 0 ) {

}
```

but I'm a bit baffled as to how to take it further. It seems to me I need a PHP function that'll use regex to find the first `<figure>` and split the $content string at the end of its opening tag, returning both halves. But there doesn't seem to be such a function - preg_split returns the string divided at the pattern, but not the pattern itself. I'd be grateful for any advice!

Edit = = = = = = = =

In answer to Amit's question here's an example of the desired input / output

`<figure>` to `<figure class="big-image">`

`<figure class='boo'>` to `<figure class='big-image boo'>`

`<figure id="bar" class="boo">` to `<figure id="bar" class="big-image boo">`

Comment: what is the output expected, for the input provided?

Comment: Amit, I'll add to my question.

Comment: The best way is to use a dom parser

Comment: Thanks Gerald, I'll see if any other answers come up and try that if not. We have to be careful about performance, so I'm hoping some custom logic would do the job more efficiently than a library set up to handle all DOM possibilities.

Comment: Doing this might be easier with JavaScript if you have jQuery available.

Comment: Thanks Alternatex, unfortunately I'm obliged to do it in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I am not on system now so cannot write a code but just follow a simple procedure.

1. get the post content in a variable using "the_content" or whatever you like.
2. check if `"<figure"` come in the content.
3. Read the string starting from `"<figure"` to first `">"` char by char and save them in other variable lets say $remove_it .
4. Now using $remove_it preg replace the post content.
5. Resulting variable will return the required result.

If you have any other query contact me directly on my new blog http://www.sourabhmodi.in/. I will be happy to help you out.